# Symfony2 Dynamic OneToOne relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have main entity for Advertisement with name: Ad.
Ad entity contains some basic data like author, date, type, etc.

And I have second entities: AdFlat, AdCar, AdHouse.
This entities have different fields that extends my Ad entity.

I need create dynamic OneToOne relation, or ManyToMany(if this need) based on category id which I get from request.

For example:

```
?category_id=1 Relation: Ad -> AdFlat
?category_id=2 Relation: Ad -> AdHouse
?category_id=3 Relation: Ad -> AdCar
```

How I can do this? Or may you propose to me better decision?

Comment: So you mean that `Ad` has a category property, and that `AdFlat`, `AdHouse`, `AdCar` extend `Ad`? If that is the case, I will have a solution for you!

Comment: See if inheritance will do what you want: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try to understand this. And next question: what inheritance will be better in my variant? AdFlat/AdHouse/AdCar have different fields like square, speed, etc. I need create table for each entity? Or I can put it on table? May be you write to me your skype or others messagers?

Comment: Cerad, thanks. After your link I understand how it's may work! Great link, thank you very much!